# Rails4: where and how to set HABTM relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've got a basic auto-generated Rails4 project with 2 tables that have mutual HABTM relationships:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
end
```

The corresponding join table also exists (called `pages_topics`) and seems to work correctly.

I've figured out using `rails console` that I can associate the two tables using `create` and `<<` for new and existing entries respectively:

```
Page.find(1).topics.create(tname: "topic name") ## for new topics

Page.find(1).topics << Topic.find(3) ## for existing topics
```

However, I'm not sure how to put these to work in my code.

- Do I add these to my controller class(es) in the controller's `create` and `update` methods?
- If so, how do I do that in conjunction with the typical `params.require(...).permit(...)` param protection pattern?

Or is there a better way to do this that I haven't learned yet?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a join table to manage the relationships. Check out the Rails guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for more. Once all that's set up you can modify your forms (if you want or need to) and your controller's `create` method to build however many siblings/parents/children you need.

```
def new
  @page = Page.new
  @page.build_topic
  2.times do # or something like this
    @page.topic.build 
  end
end
```

By virtue of their relationship you can invert that controller code to build relationships the opposite way.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that I have the join table set up and it seems to work correctly. I'll update my original question. Once all of the tables are set up though, where does one usually put the code to make the associations? In the controller methods or elsewhere?

Comment: So you want to know how to _establish_ those relationships?

Comment: I think so... like I mentioned in my post, I think I understand how to make the associations using the console, but I'm not sure where or how to put those associations into the project code itself.

Answer (score 0):

put your code in controller if you want list of topics for specific page(Id)  then put your code in pagesController.rb and if you want to make relation with list of page related to specific topic(id) then put your code in topicsController.rb. and If you have any other thing to ask then please specify clearly so that I can understand and answer you as per your need.